# How can I get other users of a shared google sheet to be able to execute this timestamp script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sharing, google-workspace, collaboration

Uneducated hobbyist trying to make a roster change sheet for a pen and paper fantasy football-esque game.

I cobbled together this script that would insert timestamps in the column adjacent to the column where data is entered. Works great for me, but not for anyone else.

[Roster Change Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nFAmNeTmCFogTdFLNZA8h_2H7SJx3o6Csuo5F0BSp8g/edit?usp=sharing)

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 1;
var COLUMNTOCHECK3 = 3;
var COLUMNTOCHECK5 = 5;
var COLUMNTOCHECK7 = 7;
var COLUMNTOCHECK9 = 9;
var COLUMNTOCHECK11 = 11;
var COLUMNTOCHECK13 = 13;
var COLUMNTOCHECK15 = 15;
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
var SHEETNAME = 'Roster Changes'

function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK3) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK5) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK7) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK9) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK11) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK13) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK15) {
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

It's trash code as I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm just trying to get 7 other specific people to be able to only edit their respective columns (got this part working in Sheets), but to also add the timestamp of when they did it (so I can be sure when they requested the roster change).

Any help appreciated. I'm way out of my depth.

Comment: Actually I don't think there's a way to make this work, since I wanted to have the date submitted column protected, but the other users need permission to edit it in order for the script to work in the first place. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible. Even with the protected range! :D You need to install [an onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

> To manually create an installable trigger through a dialog in the script editor, follow these steps:
>
> 1. From the script editor, choose **Edit > Current project's triggers**.
> 2. Click the button that says: **+ Add Trigger**.
> 3. Under **Run**, select the name of the function you want to trigger (**onEdit**).
> 4. Under **Events**, select the Google App that the script is bound to: **From spreadsheet**.
> 5. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create: an **On edit** trigger.
> 6. Optionally, click **Notifications** to configure how and when you are contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
> 7. Click **Save**.

*Instructions amended to represent changes to the process that haven't been documented and to reflect asker's needs.*

---

Here's how you can write your code **DRY** (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself).

*This code assumes the timestamp is always on the same row*

```
function onEdit() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var sheetName = 'Roster Changes'

    if (sheet.getName() === sheetName) {

        var columnsToCheck = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15];
        var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
        var col = cell.getColumn();

        if (columnsToCheck.indexOf(col) > -1) {

            var dateTimeCell = cell.offset(0, 1);
            // offset(row, column)
        
            dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```